# Simple check to see if mysql is up with Nagios

Tags: mysql, monitoring, nagios

Is there a simple check to see if MySQL is up on a host with Nagios without authenticating and selecting a table?

Comment: - added the mysql tag to this post

Answer (score 2):

You can check by using tcp connections, but authenticating is definitely preferred.

One other thing to keep in mind, without authenticating properly eventually mysql will block your monitoring host for remote mysql connections due to errors and you'll have to run 'mysqladmin flush' to give it access again.

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to connect to the database directly, you have some limitations. If you just want to see if the MySQL process is running on the host then using a plugin like **check_ps** would do the trick http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_ps-2Esh/details.

Alternatively, as other posters have said, using **check_tcp** on port 3306 will give you an idea of if mysql is up and listening on its default port, this also has the benefit of working without having already configured NRPE or setting up check_by_ssh commands.

Comment: Thanks, so is the following correct in the server config:

define service{
        use             generic-service 
        host_name               servone
        service_description     MYSQL
        check_command   check_tcp!-p3306
        }

I get "Port must be positive integer error" in the web interface.

Ill have a look at the check_ps solution.

Comment: for your check_command try just using 3306 (take out the "-p"), also take a look at your commands.cfg and make sure you are defining the check correctly, it is always good to run a pre-flight check with /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg (your directory locations may differ depending on how you installed nagios, change accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that mysql can be configured not to listen on a TCP socket at all. It will then use local UNIX socket. In that case, check_ps + NRPE would work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see other solution with this but check_tcp pluging do basically the job for you.

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_tcp -H hostname -p 3306
```